# How to do backpropagation only on a select few labels instead of all labels in a multilabel classification?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, backpropagation, multilabel-classification, resnet

I am using a pretrained neural network (resnet) on multiple datasets.

This neural network would have in it's output all the labels that are present in all the datasets,that is, like an union of all labels.

For example:

**If dataset A has labels x,y,z,w**

**Dataset B has labels -m,l,n,o,x,y**

**Dataset C has labels-w,z,m,o**

Then the neural network would have all labels **in it's final layer-that is->m,l,n,o,w,x,y,z.**

Now depending on which dataset I have, I want the model to train only on the dataset's own labels and not do *backpropagation* on other labels.

How can this be achieved?
I am working in Pytorch.

Comment: This all depends on your loss function. What are you using?

Comment: @Ivan I have been using Bcewithlogitsloss?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use three loss functions each of which has different values for the argument *pos_weight* such that it has zeros corresponding to the classes not included in a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you care if the network does backpropagation on other labels? That is how it is supposed to work.

If the idea is to reduce the number of output features from what they have in the pretrained network, just remove the last layer of the network and add in your own with the desired output features. Then train as you would.